# Gradient then color background?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a css `background-image` be a top-to-bottom gradient, and then a color. For example, if I wanted gradient that's #FF0000 at the top, #00FF00 400 pixels from the top, and immediately cuts to #EFEFEF after that, how would it be done? Is there some form of `background-image-repeat` I could use?

Comment: What's wrong with two divs? One with gradient one with color? Why over-complicate matters? K.I.S.S.

Comment: If you have a gradient and you want the bottom to be a certain color, you could just [extend the bottom color](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+0,157fd6+35,a9b9c6+75;Custom). If all you really want is a background and an overlay, then just use two elements.

Comment: @TigOldBitties because I will have an element that spans the two areas, and I want everything in a div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual property is called `background-repeat`. You need to use it in conjunction with `background-size` to restrict the gradient to 400 pixels tall and prevent it from tiling:

```
html {
    background-color: #efefef;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ff0000, #00ff00);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 400px;
}
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/dGCJs)

Of course, this assumes you're using a CSS3 gradient, in which case browser support isn't an issue as all browsers that implement CSS3 gradients also implement `background-size`. But if you're using an image file for your gradient and you need to support older browsers, you're going to have to create an extra element or a pseudo-element with the appropriate height and position, to contain just the gradient.

Comment: The only downside to `background-size` is that IE8 and below don't support it.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Whoops, I'd assumed the OP was using a CSS3 gradient. I edited my answer.

Comment: What was that line in Scooby Doo about "those darn kids always ruinin' all my plans"?

Comment: @Jared: ["And I would have gotten away with it, too, if it hadn't been for you meddling kids!"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouMeddlingKids)

Comment: There you go! Totally appropriate. `:D`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `background-color` and a gradient, set the proper `background-repeat` & `background-size`.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3687162)

```
background: #EFEFEF linear-gradient(#FF0000, #00FF00) repeat-x;
background-size: 1px 400px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a 3rd stop to your gradient is also an option (in case there are browsers that support gradients but not background-size).  Place the 2nd and 3rd stops right at 400px, with the color for the 3rd gradient as your desired bg color.